# Tor browser only opens https URLS using it along privoxy

Tags: tor, privoxy

I've configured TOR with privoxy I think in a right way, I mean I've done the following things:

If I enter in tor address bar config.privoxy.org I get that it's enabled.

In manual configuration of the proxy I've set:

HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1 Port:8118

SOCKS Server: 127.0.0.1 Port9150

SOCKs 5

Don't use proxy for

localhost,127.0.0.1

I've also uncommented the socks5-server line en privoxy config file.

If I open an https web page, it works correctly, but a http one gives the error:

Privoxy was unable to socks5-forward your request [URL] through 127.0.0.1: socks5 server unreachable

Hope you can guide me about what I can be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the port No. to 9150 In line 1314, of Privoxy config.file ?
It should look like this: `forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9150 .`
And in the 'Don't use proxy for' field in your browser, leave it blank.